# Android - Copy remote database's contents to a local database with SQLite

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite

I have a remote SQL database (i.e. a database stored in a server). I am developing an Android app that regularly stablishes a connection to copy all the remote database's tables (and their contents) to a local database using SQLite.

Is there any standardized way to perform this action within the Android SDK?

***What I've though:***

I thought about requesting the remote database's contents in JSON format, then parsing that JSON code in Android, then including it in the local database using SQLite. Don't know how efficient this is for large amounts of data, neither if there exists a better (*less painful*) approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this.  Nor could there really be-  way too many possible ways people would want to tweak things, its something better left up to developers or 3rd party libraries.

Really the easiest way is just to build a SQLite db once an hour or so on the server and have the clients download that file.  That way you don't have to do the complicated and expensive JSON parsing and SQLite insertion.  Of course you're always going to be a bit out of date this way, but if that's a concern you need to question whether local caching is a good idea at all.

Comment: That's actually probably more clever than importing the data in some intermediate format. There would be some lag with any solution not using an actual live db connection anyway..

Comment: @Gabe Sechan The remote SQL database has already been built and is strongly populated now (with dozens of tables, columns and data). Do you think converting SQL to SQLite (so to allow for "database downloading from Android") is cheaper (in terms of hours) than having to implement a JSON parser and SQLite insertion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes.  You'd more or less have to do that anyway-  you can write the server side script to SELECT * from TABLEX then loop over the cursor and INSERT into the SQLite db (remember SQLite also exists on desktops, you can just have 2 db handles in your app).  Should be a pretty trivial script-  create all the tables, loop over, and insert.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be theoretically possible to implement a connection to a remote database, I think your own idea makes sense. Implement a standard restful web service in front of the db, or investigate existing out of the box solutions for such a service, and return data using json. Parse the json and store it in the local sqlite.